# Wordpress: mysql query to return posts from specific categry - and keywords?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Wordpress / Custom MySQL queries

I've got a query to return all posts from a specific category:

```
SELECT  ID, post_title, post_name, guid, post_date, post_content, guid FROM wp_posts as p
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON
(p.ID = tr.object_id AND
tr.term_taxonomy_id IN (4) )
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON
(tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id AND
taxonomy = 'category')
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

But I also need this query to return the keywords associated with each post.  I started to create a "keywords by post ID" query, but realized that would be a very costly call when repeated.

Any idea on how to request the keywords/terms for each post that comes back?  Comma-separated would work, I guess?

**SOLUTION:**

No pretty way to do it in MySQL -- joining all those tables can be nasty.  So, the solution is three steps:

1) get the posts:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, post_title, post_name, guid, post_date, post_content, guid , GROUP_CONCAT(k.term_taxonomy_id) as keywords FROM wp_posts as p
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON
(p.ID = tr.object_id AND
tr.term_taxonomy_id IN (4) )
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships as k ON
(p.ID = k.object_id)
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON
(tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id AND
taxonomy = 'category')
GROUP BY p.ID
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

The "group_concat" will return "keywords" back as comma-separated ID's

2) get the keywords from wp_terms

3) use PHP to look up keywords from that array (#2) as needed

Comment: Can you tell us how you'll be using the data? There are built-in WordPress queries which will return that data without having to do custom MySQL queries if you just want to output this on a site...

Comment: I'm making this call outside of Wordpress and do not wish to include the WP libraries - thus the need for a direct MySQL call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all keywords and posts ids with another query and combine both results in higher level (PHP - I guess you use it). You will call database only twice, however you will have to write more logic in PHP level.

2nd result would look like this:

```
post_id | keyword 
-----------------
      2 | keyword1
      2 | keyword2 
      3 | keyword3 
      4 | keyword2 
      4 | keyword10
```

Comment: Thanks.  As I mentioned, I'm trying to avoid this because I need to request a LOT of these (sometimes up in the thousands) and do not want to make a 2nd MySQL call for each.

Comment: You didn't understand me. You call 2nd query which return result like I added to my answer. No matter how many posts you have you call only two sql queries: first that return all the post in the category you want and 2nd which return all the keywords with posts ids. See table above (edited)

Comment: Ah I see - so call all the posts, then all the keywords and use PHP to match them up?  If that's the case, how would I request the keyword ID's for each post in my original call?  (I assume I'd use that as the key)